# DbContext throws exception on query when accessed through interface

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-4.1

I have created an interface that my DbContext class implements, this enables me to create a fake db context for unit testing. This works well for all my LINQ queries so far but one, where I get the following exception:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'DemoApp.Member'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.
```

Executing the LINQ query through the interface throws the above exception, however when executing the exact same query directly on my DBContext the query works 100%. Here is the interface and related demo code definitions:

```
    interface IDemoContext : IDisposable
{
    IDbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
    IDbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}

public partial class DemoContext : DbContext, IDemoContext
{
    public DemoContext() : base("name=DemoContext"){}

    public IDbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}

public partial class Member
{
    public Member()
    {
        this.SecondaryTeams = new HashSet<Team>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? PrimaryTeamID { get; set; }

    public virtual Team PrimaryTeam { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Team> SecondaryTeams { get; set; }
}

public partial class Team
{
    public Team()
    {
        this.PrimaryMembers = new HashSet<Member>();
        this.SecondaryMembers = new HashSet<Member>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Member> PrimaryMembers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Member> SecondaryMembers { get; set; }
}
```

Each member potentially belongs to a single primary team, and optionally many secondary teams. The following demo code throws the exception:

```
using (IDemoContext dbi = new DemoContext())
        {
            var members =
                (from member in dbi.Members
                select new
                {
                    Name = member.Name,
                    Team = member.PrimaryTeam.Name,
                    SecondaryTeams = from secondaryTeam in member.SecondaryTeams
                        join primaryMember in dbi.Members
                        on secondaryTeam.ID equals primaryMember.PrimaryTeamID
                        into secondaryTeamMembers
                        select new
                        {
                            Name = secondaryTeam.Name,
                            Count = secondaryTeamMembers.Count()
                        }
                }).ToList();
        }
```

If I change the first line to:

```
using (DemoContext dbi = new DemoContext())
```

then the query executes perfectly.

So my questions are:

1. Why does it work through DemoContext and not IDemoContext?
2. How do I change IDemoContext so this query does work through the interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing `dbi.Members` with a local variable in the query.

```
    using (IDemoContext dbi = new DemoContext())
    {
        IQueryable<Member> memberSet = dbi.Members;

        var members =
            (from member in memberSet
            select new
            {
                Name = member.Name,
                Team = member.PrimaryTeam.Name,
                SecondaryTeams = from secondaryTeam in member.SecondaryTeams
                    join primaryMember in memberSet
                    on secondaryTeam.ID equals primaryMember.PrimaryTeamID
                    into secondaryTeamMembers
                    select new
                    {
                        Name = secondaryTeam.Name,
                        Count = secondaryTeamMembers.Count()
                    }
            }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: With this change it now throws a new exception: Object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[DemoApp.Member]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet`1[DemoApp.Member]'. This exception is thrown on both IDemoContext as well as DemoContext.

Comment: @Beyers Basically `memberset` has to be of type `IQueryable<Member>`. Updated answer.

Comment: Awesome, this works 100% and is a better solution than my workaround with dbi.Members.Include(i => i.SecondaryTeams). Still interested to know exactly why it fails through interface and not through DBContext.

Comment: @Beyers I dont know why it fails but this is a good example to illustrate that unit testing EF dependent code does not yield expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, the trick was to Include SecondaryTeams in the query:

```
    using (IDemoContext dbi = new DemoContext())
    {
    var memberset = dbi.Members.Include(i => i.SecondaryTeams);
    var members =
        (from member in memberset
        select new
        {
            Name = member.Name,
            Team = member.PrimaryTeam.Name,
            SecondaryTeams = from secondaryTeam in member.SecondaryTeams
                                join primaryMember in memberset
                on secondaryTeam.ID equals primaryMember.PrimaryTeamID
                into secondaryTeamMembers
                select new
                {
                    Name = secondaryTeam.Name,
                    Count = secondaryTeamMembers.Count()
                }
        }).ToList();
    }
```