# LINQ query cannot be translated if DbContext is wrapped in an interface

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.3, dbcontext

I'm having a nasty problem I really can't understand.

Basically I have a DbContext defined as follows

```
public interface ISettingsContext : IDisposable 
{
    IDbSet<Site> Sites { get; }
    IDbSet<SettingGroup> Groups { get; }
    IDbSet<SettingProperty> Properties { get; }

    int SaveChanges();
}

public class SettingsContext : DbContext, ISettingsContext
{
    public SettingsContext(string connectionStringName) : base(connectionStringName)
    {
        Sites = Set<Site>();
        Groups = Set<SettingGroup>();
        Properties = Set<SettingProperty>();
    }

    public SettingsContext() : this("DefaultTestConnectionString") { }

    public IDbSet<Site> Sites { get; private set; }

    public IDbSet<SettingGroup> Groups { get; private set; }

    public IDbSet<SettingProperty> Properties { get; private set; }

    #region Model Creation

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        MapSite(modelBuilder.Entity<Site>());
        MapGroup(modelBuilder.Entity<SettingGroup>());
        MapProperty(modelBuilder.Entity<SettingProperty>());
        MapValue(modelBuilder.Entity<SiteSettingValue>());
        MapXmlValue(modelBuilder.ComplexType<XmlValue>());
        MapXmlType(modelBuilder.ComplexType<XmlTypeDescriptor>());
    }

    private void MapXmlType(ComplexTypeConfiguration<XmlTypeDescriptor> complexType)
    {
        complexType.Ignore(t => t.Type);
    }

    private void MapXmlValue(ComplexTypeConfiguration<XmlValue> complexType)
    {
        complexType.Ignore(t => t.Value);
    }

    private void MapValue(EntityTypeConfiguration<SiteSettingValue> entity)
    {
        entity.HasKey(k => new { k.PropertyId, k.SiteId }).ToTable("SiteValues", "settings");

        entity.Property(k => k.PropertyId).HasColumnName("FKPropertyID");

        entity.Property(k => k.SiteId).HasColumnName("FKSiteID");

        entity.Property(k => k.Value.RawData).HasColumnName("Value").IsMaxLength();

        entity.HasRequired(k => k.Site).WithMany(s => s.Settings).HasForeignKey(k => k.SiteId);

        entity.HasRequired(k => k.Property).WithMany().HasForeignKey(k => k.PropertyId);
    }

    private void MapProperty(EntityTypeConfiguration<SettingProperty> entity)
    {
        entity.HasKey(k => k.Id).ToTable("Properties", "settings");

        entity.Property(k => k.Id);

        entity.Property(k => k.Name);

        entity.Property(k => k.GroupId).HasColumnName("FKGroupID");

        entity.Property(k => k.PropertyDescriptor.RawData).HasColumnName("TypeDescriptor").IsMaxLength();

        entity.Property(k => k.DefaultValue.RawData).HasColumnName("DefaultValue").IsMaxLength();

        entity.HasRequired(k => k.Group).WithMany(k => k.Properties).HasForeignKey(k => k.GroupId);
    }

    private void MapGroup(EntityTypeConfiguration<SettingGroup> entity)
    {
        entity.HasKey(k => k.Id).ToTable("Groups", "settings");

        entity.Property(k => k.Id);

        entity.Property(k => k.Name);

        entity.HasMany(k => k.Properties).WithRequired(k => k.Group).HasForeignKey(k => k.GroupId);
    }

    private void MapSite(EntityTypeConfiguration<Site> entity)
    {
        entity.HasKey(k => k.Id).ToTable("Sites", "site");

        entity.Property(k => k.Id);

        entity.Property(k => k.Domain);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Since I was carrying on some tests, I started working on this context without caring about IoC and DI, so I worked directly against the concrete class itself.

So I wrote this query:

```
public class SiteSettingsLoader : ILoader<SiteSettingsModel, int> {
...
var qSiteValues = from site in context.Sites
                  let settings = site.Settings
                  select new
                  {
                          SiteId = site.Id,
                          Settings = from value in settings
                                     join property in context.Properties on value.PropertyId equals property.Id into props
                                     from property in props
                                     select new
                                     {
                                             PropertyId = property.Id,
                                             Name = property.Name,
                                             GroupId = property.GroupId,
                                             Value = value.Value,
                                             CanBeInherited = property.CanBeInherited
                                     }
                  };
```

And everything worked just fine.
The problems started when I started passing the context as the interface it implements instead of its real type.

```
using (ISettingsContext context = new SettingsContext())
using (SiteSettingsLoader loader = new SiteSettingsLoader(context))
{
    SiteSettingsStore store = new SiteSettingsStore(loader);
    dynamic settings = store.GetItem(1);
}
```

This is the error

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'Settings.Entities.SettingProperty'. Only primitive types ('such as
>   Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

How is it possible? Did Microsoft play some dirty trick with reflection?

**EDIT**:
Both XmlValue and XmlTypeDescriptor are an implementation of the following interface that we use to automatically read the content of an XML field into a proper object.

```
public interface IXmlProperty
{
    string RawData { get; set; }
    void Load(string xml);
    XDocument ToXml();
}
```

Basically we map the content of the field to the RawData property; in its setters and getters we parse/generate the string containing the XML for the database.
I know it's an ugly trick but it works and gets the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8935255/270591) to a very similar question the reason for the problem seems to be that EF does not understand the properties of your custom interface type as queryable expressions and considers the `context.Properties` collection as a collection of constant objects of type `SettingsProperty` that you want to pass into the query. Using non-primitive constant objects is not supported by EF which causes your exception.

Basically you need to use a (compile time) type that EF knows how to translate into a SQL fragment to incorporate into the whole query. That would be a `DbContext.DbSet<T>` itself or an `IQueryable<T>`:

```cs
IQueryable<SettingProperty> properties = context.Properties;
var qSiteValues = from site in context.Sites
                  let settings = site.Settings
                  select new
                  {
                      SiteId = site.Id,
                      Settings = from value in settings
                                 join property in properties
                                    on value.PropertyId equals property.Id
                                    into props
                                 from property in props
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     PropertyId = property.Id,
                                     Name = property.Name,
                                     GroupId = property.GroupId,
                                     Value = value.Value,
                                     CanBeInherited = property.CanBeInherited
                                 }
              };
```

It might be necessary to use the same trick for `context.Sites` but I am not sure.

(If the above works don't forget to upvote Eranga's linked answer because it's awesome.)

Comment: ouch, I couldn't find that question :S